# Error: BigQuery does not support temporary tables

Tags: r, dplyr, google-bigquery, dbi, bigrquery

I'm trying to join tables from two different datasets in the same project. How can I do this?

```
    library(tidyverse)
    library(bigrquery)
    
    con1 <- 
      bConnect(
        drv = bigrquery::bigquery(),
        project = PROJECT,
        dataset = "dataset_1"
      )
    con2 <- 
      bConnect(
        drv = bigrquery::bigquery(),
        project = PROJECT,
        dataset = "dataset_2"
      )
    
    A <- con1 %>% tbl("A")
    B <- con2 %>% tbl("B")
    
    inner_join(A, B,
              by = "key",
              copy = T) %>%
      collect()
```

Then I get the error: `Error: BigQuery does not support temporary tables`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely that you are using different connections to connect with the two tables. When you attempt this, R tries to copy data from one source into a temporary table on the other source.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44703608/how-to-join-tables-from-different-sql-databases-using-r-and-dplyr) and the `copy` parameter in [this documentation](https://dbplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.tbl_sql.html) (its a different package, but the principle is the same).

The solution is to only use a single connection for all your tables. Something like this:

```r
con <- 
  bConnect(
    drv = bigrquery::bigquery(),
    project = PROJECT,
    dataset = "dataset_1"
  )
    
A <- con %>% tbl("A")
B <- con %>% tbl("B")
    
inner_join(A, B,
           by = "key") %>%
  collect()
```

You may need to leave the `dataset` parameter blank in your connection string, or use `in_schema` to include the dataset name along with the table when you connect to a remote table. It's hard to be sure without knowing more about the structure of your database(s).

Comment: Thank you. Leaving `dataset` blank and specify them in the table worked. Like `tbl("dataset_1.A")` and `tbl("dataset_2.B")`